# Xilinx, Isim treatment of Verilog integer types in simulation

Tags: simulation, verilog, fpga

I'm pretty new to FPGA and Verilog, but I'm having a problem getting my code to run in the simulator they way I would expect.  It seems the Isim simulator is not "operating" on integers in my code.    Below is a snippet of the relevant code.  I'm trying to divide the clk pulse by toggling SCK_gen every time integer i reaches 10.  When I run this code in Isim, SCK_gen never changes value. Also it When I impliment the code on the FPGA, it behaves as I would expect, I can observe a pulse at 1/10 the clock frequency.  If anyone can point me in the right direction I'd be grateful.  Thanks

```
    //signals
//for SCK_clock
reg SCK_gen, SCK_hold;
integer i;
reg en_SCK;
wire neg_edge_SCK;


//SCK_generator
always @(posedge clk, posedge reset)
    if (reset)
        begin 
            SCK_gen <= 0;
        end
    else
        begin
            i <= i+1;
            SCK_hold <= SCK_gen;
                if(i == 10)
                    begin
                        SCK_gen <= ~SCK_gen;
                        i <= 0;
                    end
        end

//detect neg edge of SCK
assign neg_edge_SCK = SCK_hold & SCK_gen;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of any arithmetic or logical equality operation is 'x' if any of the operands are 'x'. Since it looks like `i` is not initialized, the statement `i <= i+1` has no effect on `i` and so the comparison `(i == 10)` will always be false.

Comment: I figured part of this out right after I posted.  I fixed this problem with an **initial** statement.  So just to see if I got this right, if you don't specify an initial value to a reg or variable, then in the simulation it's value is **x** until assigned a value.  On the other hand though, when they are implemented in hardware they take a **0** value.  Is this correct?  Also should I comment out my **initial** statements before synthesis and implementation in hardware, or are those usually ignored?

Comment: Yes. Not always, this just happens to be the behavior of your tool chain and target hardware. The simulator has no way of knowing this from an RTL description therefore it marked the signal as unknown.